# Counting stable discs in Othello

Tags: algorithm, reversi, othello

I'm coding a Othello (Reversi) engine, and I want to count the number of stable tokens for each player, but I don't know what's the best way of doing it.

I can easily count the stable pieces along the edge, but I'm not sure how to account for the other ones. Currently, I'm using a 1-D array to represent the board.

Comment: start by carefully defining your term 'stable piece' - that should lead you down the algortihmic path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi

> "generally, a piece is stable when, along all four axes (horizontal,
>   vertical, and each diagonal), it is on a boundary, in a filled row, or
>   next to a stable piece of the same color."

You've mentioned the boundaries already - filled rows can be checked by just counting the pieces, though there are probably many optimisations here, e.g. find the filled rows first and then mark each position on the full row as potentially stable, rather than iterating over every position and then checking all the relevant directions, which will lead to wasted effort.

[This page](http://pressibus.org/ataxx/autre/minimax/node3.html) has some more details on calculating stability.

If you are interested in computer Othello, make sure you look up the [publications](http://skatgame.net/mburo/publications.html) on [Logistello](http://skatgame.net/mburo/log.html), which was (at least a few years ago) the world champion. The author, Michael Buro, wrote his PhD thesis on this topic. The source code is now available, so you can inspect the data structures used. From memory, I think he used ternary numbers (i.e. values black, white, empty) to enable fast lookups - and also maintained the state of various patterns (rows, columns, diagonals, corners, and others) to speed up the evaluation function.

Comment: Hmm...so i think there's no easy way to compute that..so i'll just count the stable pieces on the edges, that are trivial.I'll take a look at Logistello, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, it belongs on your datastructure I think. To check if a piece is stable you must check if all fields next to it (horizontal, vertical, diagonal) are following one of these rules:

- It is a boundary
- It is a stable piece of the same color
- It is in a filled row

How you would check this depends on your datastructure.
Maybe you can chose a 2 dimensional array, so you have a closer 'picture' to the real gameboard, a 8x8 matrix.

Comment: I can manage the boundary stable pieces and the filled rows. The problem is the second option: to discover the stable pieces on the middle of the board.

Answer (score 0):

**Direct Answer**

Simply go through the board in a spiral pattern, keeping track of which discs you found to be stable. If a token is directly adjacent to a stable disc of the same color or is directly adjacent to a border in all four directions (horizontal, vertical, left diagonal, right diagonal), then it will be stable - as that is the definition of a stable disc.

Example diagram for spiral:

[image: Diagram]

If you encounter a "loop" that lacks any stable discs, then you can stop searching the inner spiral as there will not be anymore stable discs. Moreover, to optimize it, you can first check if a corner is taken, if there isn't, there will be no stable discs *at all*.

You can read more about it in this [research paper](https://compsci.sites.tjhsst.edu/ai/othello_heuristics.pdf).

**Additional Thoughts**

If you are using the number of stable discs as part of a heuristic, would it not be more prudent to also check the number of unstable and semistable discs? In this case, the spiral wouldn't be applicable and you should check the stability of every disc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [bitboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitboard), you can identify multiple stable pieces at once greatly reducing the number of loop iterations necessary.

Assuming an 8-by-8 board, a position be by represented by two 64-bit bitmasks.  One mask has a bit set for each square occupied by a white disc and the other has a bit set for each square occupied by a black disc.  By using bitwise operations, (and, or, shift, etc.), you can test characteristics of several pieces at once.

My implementation is built up from some basic building blocks.

```cpp
using Mask = std::uint64_t;

Mask constexpr kEmptySet        = 0ULL;
Mask constexpr kTopRow          = 0xFF00000000000000ULL;
Mask constexpr kLeftColumn      = 0x8080808080808080ULL;
// etc.
```

I have eight functions that shift a Mask one position.  The trick to these is to mask away the squares that would be shifted off the edges of board.

```cpp
constexpr Mask ShiftN(Mask m)  { return (m & ~kTopRow                 ) << 8; }
constexpr Mask ShiftNE(Mask m) { return (m & ~(kTopRow | kRightColumn)) << 7; }
constexpr Mask ShiftE(Mask m)  { return (m & ~kRightColumn            ) >> 1; }
// etc.
```

[The abbreviations are compass directions:  north, northeast, etc.]

```cpp
Mask ComputeStability(Mask black, Mask white) {
    assert((black & white) == kEmptySet);
```

Compute a Mask that identifies pieces are stable horizontally, another for vertically, and two more for the diagonals.  A piece is stable if it's in all four of these masks.

For the first pass, those four masks are based strictly on occupancy.  For example, if a row is completely occupied, then all of the squares in that row will be set in `stable_horizontally`.

```cpp
    Mask const occupied = black | white;

    // occupancy pass
    Mask stable_horizontally = kEmptySet;
    for (Mask row = kTopRow; row != kEmptySet; row = ShiftS(row)) {
        if ((occupied & row) == row) {
            stable_horizontally |= row;
        }
    }
    // ... similar loops for columns and both diagonals...

    Mask stable = stable_horizontally & stable_vertically &
                  stable_diagonally_1 & stable_diagonally_2;
```

(For maximum speed, check what your compiler produces from this and benchmark it.  Experiment with unrolling the loops and tricks to replace conditional jumps with arithmetic or conditional moves.)

The occupancy pass runs only once.  Next, comes the inductive loop that finds pieces that are stable because their neighbors are stable.  You run that step at least once and repeat as long as it finds at least one more stable piece.

```cpp
    Mask prime = stable;
    do {
        stable = prime;

        // ... add squares to prime per the inductive rules
        // described below ...

   } while (prime != stable);

   return prime;
}
```

Note that there's no inner loop.  The inductive steps are just bitwise operations.  There are two inductive rules to apply:

1. A disc is stable if its neighbors are stable (regardless of color).

   If we make two Masks by shifting the stable discs east and west, and bitwise-and those together, we'll end up with a Mask the contains all of the squares that are horizontally between two stable discs.

   There's one trick though, and that's to realize that all of the squares beyond the edge of the board are essentially occupied by stable discs.  When we shift the stable bitmasks, we need to include these hypothetical, offboard, stable discs:

```cpp
        // Chips between stable chips are stable.
        stable_horizontally =
            (ShiftE(stable) | kLeftColumn) &
            (ShiftW(stable) | kRightColumn) & occupied;

        // ... similarly for the other directions ...

        prime |= stable_horizontally & stable_vertically &
                 stable_diagonally_1 & stable_diagonally_2;
```

2. A disc is stable if it's adjacent to a stable disc of the same color.

   This is done in the same way, but the expressions are different, notably because the disc colors are relevant (except for the hypothetical, off-the-edge pieces).

```cpp
        // Chips adjacent to a stable chip of the same color are stable.
        stable_horizontally =
            ((ShiftE(stable & black) | kLeftColumn)  & black) |
            ((ShiftW(stable & black) | kRightColumn) & black) |
            ((ShiftE(stable & white) | kLeftColumn)  & white) |
            ((ShiftW(stable & white) | kRightColumn) & white);

        // similarly for the other directions

        prime |= stable_horizontally & stable_vertically &
                 stable_diagonally_1 & stable_diagonally_2;
```

This approach is cache friendly, computes results for several squares at a time, and the loops have small bounds.  Further optimization is possible, but if you've got 64-bit registers and a decent optimizing compiler, it might not be worth it.

To *count* the number of stable discs for each color, you simply bitwise-and the returned stability Mask with each color and count the number of bits set.